# ubuntu vm returning internal ip to docker image

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, docker, multipass

I have a docker image running on multipass on a physical host. The docker container is trying to connect to a service running on the physical host. However, dns resolution tells docker that the ip address is `127.0.1.1`.  I think the dns lookup in the vm is returning a local ip address, when a public address is required:

```
physical host: culsu (ubuntu 18.04)
    multipass host: promlife (ip: 10.13.31.13) (ubuntu 22.04)
        docker container: prometheus (ip: 172.18.0.9)
            dns lookup of promlife: 127.0.1.1
```

I think the issue can be resolved if the dns server on `promlife` returns `10.13.31.13`

From the physical machine:

```
$ ping promlife
PING promLife (10.13.31.13) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

From the promlife vm:

```
$ ping promlife
PING promlife (127.0.1.1) 56(85) bytes of data.
```

From the docker container:

```
$ ping promlife
PING promlife (127.0.1.1) 56(85) bytes of data.
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on what I need to change to get prometheus to resolve the virtual host?

Is the issue potentially related to systemd-resolvd?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The address 127.0.1.1 is the address Linux hosts setup as the address to "itself by name" in `/etc/hosts`. When you run `ping` (or anything else that uses POSIX name resolution), it will use the `nsswitch` library to look at the `/etc/hosts` file to find the meaning of the non-fully-qualified name.

I'm not sure why from inside the container it does that - it somehow offloads to the host `nsswitch` library, maybe its a Docker thing.

Anyway, if you want to access the Docker host from within a docker container, the correct way is to use a special host name that docker automatically resolves to the docker host's IP address on the container's local network - which is called `host.docker.internal`.

Try: `ping host.docker.internal` from within your container.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the DNS configuration in **promlife**, you can edit the /etc/netplan/netcfg.yaml file. Modify the **nameservers** field to point to your preferred DNS server.

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    ens: 
      addresses: [10.13.31.13/24] # Your IP configuration
      gateway4: 10.13.31.1 # Your gateway
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8]
```

After updating the configuration, apply it.
`sudo netplan apply`
Restart the **systemd-resolved** service to make sure it picks up the changes.
`sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved`